# Vectored interrupts in Linux on x86

Tags: linux, x86, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Because of one interrupt entry point in Linux, are vectored interrupts in x86 useless or are there any benefits from it? I think that better solution is from MIPS, where is interrupt vector loaded into Cause register and that we don't have to push in each interrupt handler its number on the stack and jump to entry point, isn't so? And if not, why?

Sorry for my English.

**EDIT:**

Reference: [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596002130/ch04s06.html)

Comment: The benefit of vectored interrupts is to avoid polling all devices to see what triggered it, and Linux gets that. Saving a few instructions by jumping directly to the handler instead of a lookup table doesn't matter.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you for your answer. I think there is one problem; it doesn't make any sense in Linux to jumps directly to the handler by interrupt vector number, because here is only pushed this number on the stack and is executed jump to interrupt entry point, where is executed really dispatching and then is invoked interrupt handler. With this all, I just want to say, one vector to jump is enough and some register would hold interrupt vector that caused it, which can be used later, when dispatching. Does this have any bottleneck?